# Expected number of steps to reach 1

Tags: probability, expected-value

We start with some $A, B$ ($A, B$ are natural numbers: $A \le B$).

We repeatedly toss a fair coin to decide the next step:-
Heads: Decrement $A$ by $1$
Tails: if $A < B$, increment $A$ by $1$, else do nothing
Stop when $A = 1$.

What is the expected number of flips for $A$ to reach $1$?

Hint: For $A, B = (12, 12)$, the answer is $132$.

This question was asked as a programming problem. No, I couldn't just brute force the solution. My intuition suggests I need to form a couple inter-related expected value equations but I can't seem to figure out how. I've tried creating a tree to visualize the solution but that doesn't seem to help.

### Edit:

I've been trying to go about the problem by trying to figure out the number of flips for some expected $\delta$ for $A$.

Say, we are at $A, B = (2, 2)$. The probability of $\delta = -1$ is $0.5$, the probability of $\delta = +1$ is $0$, and the probability of $\delta = 0$ is $0.5$. Therefore, the expected value of $\delta$ is $-0.5$ and so for a decrement of $1$ we can expect $2$ flips. That is, to go from $(2, 2)$ to $(1, 2)$ we expect $2$ flips and then we can stop.

This gets out of hand immediately because for something like $A, B = (2, 3)$:
$P(\delta=-1)$ is $0.5$, $P(\delta=+1)$ is $0.5$, and $P(\delta=0)$ is $0$. So, the expected value of $\delta$ becomes $0$.

Comment: Let $e(A, B)$ be the expectation when you start with $A$ and $B$.  My hint is to try and write a recurrence relation for $e(A, B)$ and then solve it. You can get the recurrence relation by thinking about what happens on the first coin toss.  You'll need a boundary condition, e.g. the value of $e(1, B)$.

Comment: This is a neat programming problem because the natural way to write a recursive function to solve the problem leads to an infinite loop (e(2, 3) depends on e(3, 3) which depends on e(2, 3) which depends on e(3, 3) which...).  You are forced to come up with a smarter way, or solve the recurrence.

Comment: @MatthewTowers I can't seem to make any progress. Can you give me some more pointers?

Comment: Is it how many steps or how many flips? Do we count the "do nothing" when $A=B$ as a step?

Comment: @JohnBarber Flips, as stated in the problem description. I say steps to mean flips only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $E_{A,B}$ denote the expected number of flips, defined whenever $1\le A\le B$. We have:

- $E_{1,B}=0$ for all $B$ (if $A=1$, we're done)
- $E_{B,B}=1+\frac12(E_{B-1,B}+E_{B,B})$ for all $B\ge 2$ (because $A$ becomes $B-1$ or $B$ with equal probability)
- $E_{A,B}=1+\frac12(E_{A-1,B}+E_{A+1,B})$ for all $2\le A<B$ (because $A$ becomes $A-1$ or $A+1$ with equal probability)

These equations have the solution
$$E_{A,B}=(A-1)(2B-A)$$

---

To arrive at this solution, I first expressed the equations in matrix form. For instance, if $B=5$ we get
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_{1,5}\\
E_{2,5}\\
E_{3,5}\\
E_{4,5}\\
E_{5,5}\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix}+\frac12
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
E_{1,5}\\
E_{2,5}\\
E_{3,5}\\
E_{4,5}\\
E_{5,5}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Rearranging,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
E_{1,5}\\
E_{2,5}\\
E_{3,5}\\
E_{4,5}\\
E_{5,5}\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
2\\
2\\
2\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
E_{1,5}\\
E_{2,5}\\
E_{3,5}\\
E_{4,5}\\
E_{5,5}\\
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
2\\
2\\
2\\
2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inv%28%7B%7B2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%2C-1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C-1%2C2%2C-1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C2%2C-1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C-1%2C1%7D%7D%29) evaluates this inverse as
$$
\frac12
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 6\\\
0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 8
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The pattern is clear.

We get
$$E_{1,5}=0+0+0+0+0=0$$
$$E_{2,5}=0+2+2+2+2=8$$
$$E_{3,5}=0+2+4+4+4=14$$
$$E_{4,5}=0+2+4+6+6=18$$
$$E_{5,5}=0+2+4+6+8=20$$
So each value is the sum of an arithmetic progression ($0+2+4+6+8$) minus the sum of a smaller arithmetic progression (e.g. $E_{2,5}=(0+2+4+6+8)-(2+4+6)$). If you express these in terms of $A$ and $B$, and simplify the expression, you get $(A-1)(2B-A)$.